# Variable Does Not Get Passed to Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have code that does this:

```
$('#BoxShadow_1').click(function()
{
addDivBoxShadow('BoxShadow_1');
});

$('#BoxShadow_2').click(function()
{
addDivBoxShadow('BoxShadow_2');
});
```

...etc for 10 similar elements. It works just fine.

I am using JQuery also.

I want to change the code to something like this:

```
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

    $('#BoxShadow_' + i).click(function(){
      addDivBoxShadow("BoxShadow_" + i);
    });

}
```

Challenge is this:

BoxShadow_10 is assigned to all of the divs rather than BoxShadow_1, BoxShadow_2 etc.

FYI the code I am trying to effect is a math game I wrote at this URL:

tinyurl.com/sashamath

Thanks in advance. And I hope to contribute in the future.

Ok, so here is the answer, using the 'let' statement as follows:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

    $('#BoxShadow_' + i).click(function(){
      addDivBoxShadow("BoxShadow_" + i);
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you. The key was to use:  'let' as in: for(let i = 1; i < 11; i++)

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with your loop is the classic "callback in a loop" problem. '

However you don't need a loop at all. Just use the `id` property of `this` to get the ID.

```
function handler() {
  addDivBoxShadow(this.id);
}

$('#BoxShadow_1').click(handler);
$('#BoxShadow_2').click(handler);
```

---

Or if you change the `addDivBoxShadow` function to use `this` to get the element, you can pass it directly.

```
$('#BoxShadow_1').click(addDivBoxShadow);
$('#BoxShadow_2').click(addDivBoxShadow);
```

So now `addDivBoxShadow` can use `this` to reference the bound element, and it will also receive the `event` object as an argument.

---

And of course it can be done with a single selector too.

```
$('#BoxShadow_1, #BoxShadow_2').click(addDivBoxShadow);
```